# Installing Application created on Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation

Problem: I can't open the installed program on other computers.

I created a program on visual studio 2010 with database created on sql server 2008 express. When i created the setup and install it on MY OWN PC, it runs properly together with its database. When i try to install it on other computers, it successfully installed but i cant open. When in double click the shortcut, even the .exe, it is not responding. The application is not opening/running.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is in database connection. make sure the connection string is assigned properly and server can be connectable. When application tries to connect the server which is not available then will be hanged and stop responding.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Application Eventlog for possible error details?

Comment: Have you installed sql express in that pc?

Comment: I have windows 7 Professional 64bit


I try to install it on:
Windows 8 with no sql express and in Windows 7 32bit with sql server 2008 R2


Both of them, when i open the application, the mouse pointer will load for 5 seconds and nothing will happen.


This is my connection string:
mConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\Babylon Garden RestoBar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

Comment: you have to install sql express on Windows 8 first otherwise it wont work.

Comment: uhh .. sir am i wrong that if my program do not recognize the database, it will show error the error. but this time, there is no error showing. But i will try those suggestion. Thanks sir !

Uhm, Sir Filburt, where can i see the "Windows Application Eventlog" ?

Comment: sir, is it ok if i install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP3 Express Edition ? i dont know if sql server 2008 express is available on windows 8.

Comment: @KryLeQuerubinQuimpo `Win+R` and run `eventvwr` to start the Windows Event Viewer, then navigate to the Application Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is probably trying to connect to a database that doesn't exist.  You'll need to install SQL Express on the computer where you installed the software.